# Problema NullPointer

Tags: java, eclipse

estoy por mi cuenta intentado realizar un framework con cucumber en Selenium de un carrito de la compra de Amazon.

Test_Steps

```
    package stepDefinition;

    import managers.PageObjectManager;
    import PageObjects.CartPage;
    import PageObjects.HomePage;
    import PageObjects.ProductListingPage;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
    import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

    public class Test_Steps {
private static WebElement Nombregrafica;
private static WebElement movil;
private String mov11;
private String mov21;
private String graficanm;
private String graficanm2;
WebDriver driver;
HomePage homePage;
ProductListingPage productListingPage;
CartPage cartPage;
PageObjectManager pageObjectManager;

@Given("User is on Home Page")
public void user_is_on_Home_Page() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".//target//Drivers//chromedriver.exe");
    // Creamos una nueva instancia de Google Chrome
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize() ;
    // Guardamos la pÃƒÂ¡gina web en una variable para poder llamarla y abrirla
    homePage = pageObjectManager.getHomePage();
    homePage.navigateTo_HomePage();
}

@When("User search product")
public void user_search_product() {
    // Ahora en el motor de busqueda escribimos lo que queremos buscar
    homePage = pageObjectManager.getHomePage();
    homePage.txtboxsearch1();
    // Ahora presionamos en la busqueda anteriorimente realizada
    productListingPage = pageObjectManager.getProductListingPage();
    productListingPage.searchproduct();
    Nombregrafica = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gigabyte Technology GeForce RTX 2060 OC GV-N2060OC-6GD - Tarjeta grafica, Negro"));
    graficanm = Nombregrafica.getText();
    productListingPage.clickfirstproduct();

}

@And("User add product to shopping cart and move to Home Page")
public void user_add_product_to_shopping_cart_and_move_to_Home_Page() {
    // Añadimos a la Cesta
    ProductListingPage productListingPage = new ProductListingPage(driver);
        productListingPage.clickadd_cart1();
       // Volvemos a la pagina principal
    homePage = pageObjectManager.getHomePage();
    homePage.navigateTo_HomePage();

}

@When("User search another product")
public void user_search_another_product() {
    // Segunda Busqueda
    // Ahora en el motor de busqueda escribimos lo que queremos buscar
    homePage = pageObjectManager.getHomePage();
    homePage.txtboxsearch2();
    // Ahora presionamos en la busqueda anteriorimente realizada
    productListingPage =pageObjectManager.getProductListingPage();
    productListingPage.searchproduct();
    movil = driver.findElement(By.linkText("AMD YD2600BBAFBOX, Procesador RYZEN5 2600 Socket AM4 3.9Ghz Max Boost, 3,4Ghz Base+19MB"));
    mov11 =movil.getText();
    productListingPage.clicksecondproduct();
}

@And("User add product to shopping cart")
public void user_add_product_to_shopping_cart() {
    // AÃƒÂ±adimos a la cesta
    productListingPage = pageObjectManager.getProductListingPage();
    productListingPage.clickONadd_cart2();

}




@Then("User checks that the products have been added to the shopping cart")
public void user_checks_that_the_products_have_been_added_to_the_shopping_cart() {
    // Observamos la cesta de que efectivamente se ha añadido los productos
    cartPage = pageObjectManager.getCartPage();
    cartPage.clickcheckcart();
    // Comprobamos que los productos son correctos
    WebElement mov2 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("AMD YD2600BBAFBOX, Procesador RYZEN5 2600 Socket AM4 3.9Ghz Max Boost, 3,4Ghz Base+19MB"));
    mov21= mov2.getText();

   WebElement grafica2 = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gigabyte Technology GeForce RTX 2060 OC GV-N2060OC-6GD - Tarjeta grafica, Negro"));
    graficanm2 = grafica2.getText();
    Assert.assertEquals(mov11,mov21);
    Assert.assertEquals(graficanm,graficanm2);

}
         }
```

Y este es mi PageObjectManager

```
    package managers;

    import PageObjects.CartPage;
    import PageObjects.HomePage;
    import PageObjects.ProductListingPage;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

    public class PageObjectManager {
        WebDriver driver;
     private HomePage homePage;
     private ProductListingPage productListingPage;
     private CartPage cartPage;

    public PageObjectManager(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;

    }
    public HomePage getHomePage() {
        return (homePage == null) ? homePage= new HomePage(driver): homePage;
    }

    public ProductListingPage getProductListingPage() {
    return (productListingPage == null) ? productListingPage= new ProductListingPage(driver) :productListingPage;
     }

    public CartPage getCartPage(){
    return (cartPage == null) ? cartPage = new CartPage(driver) : cartPage;
    }
}
```

Cuando intento correr el Test me da este error,

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin\java.exe" -ea -DnodeNamesHandler=AsText -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=61737:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\IdeaProjects\SeleniumCucumberV.1\target\test-classes;C:\Users\Usuario\IdeaProjects\SeleniumCucumberV.1\target\classes;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-java\3.141.59\selenium-java-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-api\3.141.59\selenium-api-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-chrome-driver\3.141.59\selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-edge-driver\3.141.59\selenium-edge-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.141.59\selenium-firefox-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-ie-driver\3.141.59\selenium-ie-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-opera-driver\3.141.59\selenium-opera-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-remote-driver\3.141.59\selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-safari-driver\3.141.59\selenium-safari-driver-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.8.15\byte-buddy-1.8.15.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-exec\1.3\commons-exec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\25.0-jre\guava-25.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-compat-qual\2.0.0\checker-compat-qual-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.1.3\error_prone_annotations-2.1.3.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.1\j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.14\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okhttp3\okhttp\3.11.0\okhttp-3.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\com\squareup\okio\okio\1.14.0\okio-1.14.0.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-support\3.141.59\selenium-support-3.141.59.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.12\junit-4.12.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-java\4.7.2\cucumber-java-4.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-core\4.7.2\cucumber-core-4.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\gherkin\5.1.0\gherkin-5.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\tag-expressions\1.1.1\tag-expressions-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-expressions\7.0.2\cucumber-expressions-7.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable\1.1.14\datatable-1.1.14.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\datatable-dependencies\1.1.14\datatable-dependencies-1.1.14.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-java\1.2.5\cucumber-java-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-core\1.2.5\cucumber-core-1.2.5.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-html\0.2.3\cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\io\cucumber\cucumber-junit\4.7.2\cucumber-junit-4.7.2.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\info\cukes\cucumber-jvm-deps\1.0.5\cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\info\cukes\gherkin\2.12.2\gherkin-2.12.2.jar;C:\Users\Usuario\.m2\repository\org\picocontainer\picocontainer\2.15\picocontainer-2.15.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 cucumbertest.TestRunner
    Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70 (edb9c9f3de0247fd912a77b7f6cae7447f6d3ad5-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#800}) on port 46576
    Only local connections are allowed.
   Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to 
   prevent access by malicious code.
  [1576923269.778][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been 
  tested with Chrome version 79.
  [1576923271.784][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
  dic 21, 2019 11:14:33 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake 
  createSession
  INFORMACIÓN: Detected dialect: W3C
  [1576923275.832][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...

 java.lang.NullPointerException
at stepDefinition.Test_Steps.user_is_on_Home_Page(Test_Steps.java:37)
at ✽.User is on Home Page(file:src/test/resources/carrito.feature:5)


 Process finished with exit code -1
```

Este es mi

HomePage

```
      package PageObjects;

       import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
       import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
      import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
     import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

    public class HomePage{
        WebDriver driver;
public  HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

    @FindBy (how = How.ID,using = "twotabsearchtextbox")
    private WebElement txtboxsearch;


public void txtboxsearch1() {
    txtboxsearch.sendKeys("Gigabyte 2060 RTX");
}

public void txtboxsearch2(){
    txtboxsearch.sendKeys("Ryzen 5 2600");
}

public void navigateTo_HomePage() {
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.es/");
}


 package PageObjects;

 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

 public class HomePage{
        WebDriver driver;
public  HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

    @FindBy (how = How.ID,using = "twotabsearchtextbox")
    private WebElement txtboxsearch;


public void txtboxsearch1() {
    txtboxsearch.sendKeys("Gigabyte 2060 RTX");
}

public void txtboxsearch2(){
    txtboxsearch.sendKeys("Ryzen 5 2600");
}

public void navigateTo_HomePage() {
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.es/");
}
}
```

Y este mi testRunner

```
   package cucumbertest;

   import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
    features = "src/test/resources"
    ,glue ={"stepDefinition"}
)

   public class TestRunner {
}
```

Si no implemento el PageObjectManager, no me da error, por eso supongo que le problema esta en la relación entre uno y otro.

El error me da siempre el mismo, este caso me da desde que empiezo intentando llevarlo a Amazon.

Soy nuevo en esto y me estoy buscando yo solo la vida con tutos y demás, así que perdón de antemano por cualquier error que pueda cometer. Gracias :)

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta la traza completa del error? Para hacerlo pulsa en [edit].

Comment: A esto te refieres ? . los demás me ocurren el mismo problema, tire del productlistingpage o lo que sea por eso me imagino que todos tendran el mismo problema de que le falte o le sobre algo :P jja

Comment: Me refiero a eso. Debes poner atención a lo que dice el mensaje de error. Dice que hay un posible problema de seguridad en la llamada que haces a ChromeDriver. Hay mensajes del tipo:  `Only local connections are allowed` y también `Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code`

Comment: pero ese error siempre da desde el principio que llevo haciendo lo mas básico, y he podido hacer todo hasta ahora, eso es un tema interno del firewall de windows seguramente, si luego cualquiera se lo quiere bajar de github tendrá el mismo problema no ? En otro PC en otra casa he ido descargando y probando y ha estado todo funcionando OK.

Comment: Ok. El NPE parece ocurrir aquí: `src/test/resources/carrito.feature`, parece que eso apunta a un recurso que no existe. Debes verificar si en `resources` hay algo que se llama `carrito.feature`. Si lo hay entonces no está reconociendo bien la ruta, puedes probar con una ruta absoluta al recurso que quieres usar ahí para ver si funciona.

Comment: El feature me lo reconoce, incluso ya previamente lo puse en esa dirección que esta mejor puesta que donde la tenia, aunque en su anterior ubicación funcionaba, pero era por tenerlo todo mas limpio, por que si yo no implemente el Pageobjectmanager y tiro directamente de los homepage productlistingpage etc me lo hace perfectamente, es en el momento en el que implemento el pageobjectmanager en el test_step cuando da error

Comment: Si yo por ejemplo pongo 
HomePage home = new HomePage(driver);
 home.txtboxsearch1;
que es el paso previo en el tuto todo anda correctamente y me hace las busquedas etc etc. es a la hora de usar el pageobjectmanager para tenerlo todo mas centralizado cuando empiezan los problemas :/

Comment: vale el error en Home page ya lo tengo solucionado, me faltaba añadir
pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager(driver); 
:') ahora voy a seguir con los demas apartados aver si consigo hacerlo todo jaj por que me dan tb NPE

Comment: Tienes que leer los mensajes de error y revisar siempre lo que ocurre en la línea donde dice *`Caused by ...`*, significa que en esa línea hay un elemento nulo. A veces te dice qué elemento es, como en este caso, hacía referencia al `carrito.feature` que por el motivo que expones se estaba creando mal o no se encontraba.

Comment: Ya ya, no pero el feature esta bien, era error que no llamaba de primeras al PageobjectManager, estoy solucionando todos los demas errores y ya casi lo tengo listo este apartado. Igualmente Gracias, supongo me iran saliendo mas dudas que intentare no preguntar a no ser que me tire 3 dias como con esta aun buscandome la vida sin poder solucionarlo y luego es lo mas tonto xD

Comment: Bueno no esperes tres días para preguntar. Cuando tengas 3 horas sin encontrar el problema pregunta. La clave es aprender bien a depurar el código, leyendo atentamente los mensajes de error. Tienes que revisar bien la línea donde te indica el error y seguir la traza si fuera necesario. El log de errores te va poniendo desde el punto en que falla, en orden inverso, las líneas que se relacionan con ese punto del código. Casi siempre el error está en el punto preciso o en uno anterior.